# Spring JPA doesn't work with my encoding(UTF-8) only when I use update data

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use Spring Data JPA and it works well with my encoding(utf-8) when I first insert data.
Problme is that the characters(Korean) change like ã…ã…ã…ã…ã… when I update exist data.
I'm using MariaDB and basic database setting is utf-8. I also changed all application.properties options to utf-8.
I don't understand why it doesn't work only when I update data. Please help me to figure it out. Thank you.

I add some code below

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:log4jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/boot?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul
spring.datasource.hikari.username=boot
spring.datasource.hikari.password=1234
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useUnicode=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.characterEncoding=UTF-8
mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false

spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

I put some log below when I create and update data

```
2021-03-16 09:06:06,105  INFO [jdbc.sqlonly] insert into t_jpa_board (contents, created_datetime, creator_id, hit_cnt, title, update_datetime, updater_id) values ('Hello = 안녕하세요', '03/16/2021 09:06:06.065', 'admin', 0, 'Error test for stackoverflow  Korean => 안녕하세요', NULL, NULL)
```

As you can see, there is no problem with the query with Korean data which JPA created, but when I click the modify button it turns into broken text as below.

```
2021-03-16 09:11:07,921  INFO [jdbc.sqlonly] update t_jpa_board set contents='Hello = ìëíì¸ì', created_datetime='03/16/2021 09:11:07.904', creator_id='admin', hit_cnt=0, title='[Modify] Error test for stackoverflow  Korean => ìëíì¸ì', update_datetime=NULL, updater_id=NULL where board_idx=4
```

I think it should have the same problem when I create data, but it is fine with creation. Please help me if you have any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Share part of your code

Comment: @kometen I add some code. If you need more info, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @Faramarz Afzali I add some code. If you need more info, please let me know. Thank you.